# Flex styles are not loaded at run time in android devices

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

i want to load my styles(in swf format) at run time for my flex mobile application. for that requirement, i have compiled my css files into swf format and i loaded for my application using "StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("style.swf");" . i get my styles for application when i run it on my desktop, but after building my files into apk format , i couldn't get the styles applied for my application in device. when i debug my application from my android device, i got the following error message.

```
Error: Unable to load style(RSL app:/framework_4.5.1.21328.swz failed to load. Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/framework_4.5.1.21328.swz): style.swf.
    at Function/<anonymous>()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\styles\StyleManagerImpl.as:1551]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at ModuleInfoProxy/moduleEventHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\modules\ModuleManager.as:1149]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at ModuleInfo/moduleErrorHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\modules\ModuleManager.as:816]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/update()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/displayError()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/rslErrorHandler()
    at mx.core::RSLListLoader/listIOErrorHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLListLoader.as:286]
    at mx.core::RSLItem/itemErrorHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLItem.as:275]
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/itemErrorHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

please help me to solve on this issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: have you install adobe air in device?

Comment: yes , i have installed it. but i can get my styles when i give it inside <fx:style> tag.

Comment: while packaging to apk , i have included the necessary style.swf in the package content.but i can't getthe styles in devices

Comment: you are make apk with adobe air sdk right?

Comment: yeah , i have built the apk file with adobe air sdk .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by Flex 4 generating unnecessary RSLs when compiling CSS files as SWF.

Todd Anderson has solved this problem by using ANT and a project called flex-runtime-css.

You can find out more here:

http://custardbelly.com/blog/2010/10/20/flex-4-and-runtime-style-sheets/